# Two side-by-side pages with pyPDF

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to create a pdf page that contains two pages side by side, with this is my code:
(python 3.11.2 and pypdf 3.5.1)

```
from pypdf import PdfWriter, PdfReader, PageObject, Transformation

reader = PdfReader(open("file.pdf", "rb"))
page1 = reader.pages[0]
page2 = reader.pages[1]

single_page = PageObject.create_blank_page(width=842, height=595)

left_page = Transformation().scale(0.7).translate(0, 0)
right_page = Transformation().scale(0.7).translate(421, 0)

page1.add_transformation(left_page)
page2.add_transformation(right_page)

single_page.merge_page(page1, expand=False)
single_page.merge_page(page2, expand=False)

output = PdfWriter()
output.add_page(single_page)
output_file = open("file_output.pdf", "wb")
output.write(output_file)
output_file.close()
```

With a simple two-page pdf file the originated file is the one attached.
Only half of the second page is regenerated even trying to move the page with the translate method I can never write beyond three quarters of the blank page.
Any help is appreciated.[file_output.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUBYF.png)

Comment: Please let me know if you are interested in a solution using PyMuPDF.

Comment: yes, I am interested, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
"""
Combines 2 input pages to become:

the left / right halves
-- OR --
the top / bottom halves

of one output page.
"""
import sys

import fitz  # PyMuPDF

infile = sys.argv[1]  # read input filename
src = fitz.open(infile)  # open by PyMuPDF
doc = fitz.open()  # empty output PDF

# use first input page to compute output page size
r1 = src[0].rect  # rectangle of first page

if r1.width < r1.height:  # portrait case
    r2 = r1 + (r1.width, 0, r1.width, 0)
    width = 2 * r1.width
    height = r1.height
else:  # landscape
    r2 = r1 + (0, r1.height, 0, r1.height)
    width = r1.width
    height = 2 * r1.height

# put them in some sequence object
r_tab = (r1, r2)

# now copy input pages to output
for spage in src:
    if spage.number % 2 == 0:  # create new output page
        page = doc.new_page(width=width, height=height)
    # insert input page into the correct rectangle
    page.show_pdf_page(
        r_tab[spage.number % 2],  # select output rect
        src,  # input document
        spage.number,  # input page number
    )

# save new file using garbage collection and compression
doc.ez_save("2-up-" + infile)
```