# pypdf: arrange pages of different pdfs in a single page as a grid

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have several pdf files `1.pdf`, `2.pdf`, ..., `n.pdf`, each with 10 pages, each page being the same size.

I want to create another file `summary.pdf`

- containing **only one** page, with all the pages of all the PDFs; and
- such page should look like a kind of grid: its first row must  contain all the 10 pages of `1.pdf`, its second row to contain all the 10 pages of `2.pdf`, etc.

Is this doable with `pypdf` or another *pure* Python package?

Comment: Yes, it is doable, rescale each page accordingly and apply an affine transformation, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72754236/16462878) hope useful (not tested but looks good!) Notice that the link is old (PyPDF2) but it can be easily rewritten for `pypdf` (pypdf will give you suggestions on how the deprecated methods are called now)

Answer (score 1):

I ended doing it using the transformations of `pypdf`. I put my code below for future references.

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter, Transformation


n = 3  # number of PDF files
pdf_width = 415
pdf_height = 321

output = PdfWriter()
pdf_summary.add_blank_page(pdf_width * 10, pdf_height * n)
for i_pdf in range(n):
    source = PdfReader(f'{i_pdf + 1}'.pdf)
    for i_page, page in enumerate(pdf_source.pages):
        output.pages[0].merge_transformed_page(
            page,
            Transformation().translate(i_page * pdf_width, (n - i_pdf - 1) * pdf_height),
        )
output.write('output.pdf')
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to make a test. You need to install PyPDF2 with : **`pip install PyPDF2`**

```
import PyPDF2

def merge_pdfs(input_files, output_file):
    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

    for input_file in input_files:
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(input_file)

        for page_number in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
            page = pdf_reader.getPage(page_number)
            pdf_writer.addPage(page)

    with open(output_file, 'wb') as output_pdf:
        pdf_writer.write(output_pdf)

input_files = ['1.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf']
output_file = 'summary.pdf'
    
merge_pdfs(input_files, output_file)
```

Comment: `PyPDF2` is deprecated and the project merged into `pypdf`, the same as in the tags of the OP, [see](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/meta/history.html)

Comment: ...and even the method**s** used in your answer are [deprecated](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/meta/changelog-v1.html) as well. Use `for page in pdf_reader.pages:`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually saw this before, but I am trying to avoid deprecated packages, since I want to release a package of my own and maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple factors you need to consider before setting out such a grid.

Firstly assuming you have standard page of say 840 units there is an upper boundary of n pages (units cannot exceed 14400 without some adjustments in the PDF structure).

Thus for standard pages `n` cannot exceed 17 rows.

Secondly, the more contents the heavier a drain on available working memory. Thus the more data the less for programming efficiently. So for that reason alone it can sometimes help to chunk a task into parts then assemble those parts yet again.

Thus limit your 1st attempt to a reasonable number say 5 or 6 rows of 10.

Normally we might use a grid of 4 x 4 without a problem. Then loop that again to make 16 x 16 which is likely as much as practical.

I could attempt the whole task in a few lines of shell command , however you have limited your example to Python. Thus I suggest you follow the examples but scale them up.

PyPDF https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/cropping-and-transforming.html#transforming-several-copies-of-the-same-page this is similar to the older pyPDF2 (depreciated) example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72754236/10802527

Alternately try PyMuPDF https://stackoverflow.com/a/75705016/10802527

Many other Python wrappers may simply call on GhostScript and that is just 2 lines to do the whole job.

```
GS\10021\bin>gs -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -o Allx9Pages.pdf -f 1x9.pdf 2x9.pdf 3x9.pdf 4x9.pdf 5x9.pdf 6x9.pdf 7x9.pdf 8x9.pdf 9x9.pdf

GS\10021\bin>gs -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=5508 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=7128 -o 9x9-Pages.pdf -sNupControl=9x9 -f Allx9Pages.pdf
```

However you may need to make the controls more specific to your case as here I simply did

**9 x 9.** [Famous Band with John Dummer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZtSgiBX3bQ)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. First, I will not have more than 3 rows on each pages and 10 columns, so we should be fine. Second, I cannot use GhostScript because I am developing a Python package that will be available as a standalone.

Comment: Yes but I am building a Python library that will be available on PyPI, etc, so I need a pure Python solution as I want users not to have to install external dependencies. I managed to do it with `pypdf`, I will post the code here later today.